# Nginx sometimes crash

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, systemctl

Sometimes nginx randomly crashes (once every few months)
Here's the log I got when I ran systemctl status nginx

```
    nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset:>
     Active: failed (Result: core-dump) since Tue 2023-01-24 11:09:29 UTC; 3h 4>
       Docs: man:nginx(8)
   Main PID: 265516 (code=dumped, signal=SEGV)
      Tasks: 0 (limit: 2351)
     Memory: 15.9M
     CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service

Nov 25 08:52:52 ip-172-31-16-145 systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web se>
Nov 25 08:52:52 ip-172-31-16-145 systemd[1]: Started A high performance web ser>
Jan 24 11:09:29 ip-172-31-16-145 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Main process exited>
Jan 24 11:09:29 ip-172-31-16-145 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Killing process 631>
Jan 24 11:09:29 ip-172-31-16-145 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Killing process 631>
Jan 24 11:09:29 ip-172-31-16-145 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result >
```

I'm looking for a way to fix this or at least to restart nginx automatically when it happen.

The server is an EC2 Ubuntu instance on AWS.

Comment: you can see more of those messages, which may actually tell you why it `Failed with result`

Comment: @JaromandaX How can I see that ? I havent found a log for this anywhere (and I restarted the nginx instance since).

Comment: I'm sure that error would be in one or more of the logs in `/var/log`

Answer (score 0):

Older nginx versions contain some issues that cause core dumps.

Check nginx [changelog](http://nginx.org/en/CHANGES) to see if your setup is related and update nginx to a recent version. That will likely fix the crashes.

Comment: Updated to 1.22 (for some reason apt had 1.18 as the latest version but found a way to install a later one). I hope this will work.